# Ubuntu partitions on 1 ssd and 2 hdds

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I need help.
I want to use my 120 gb ssd for the ubuntu os,and the other 2hdds of 1tb each, for the programs and applications I will install.
Which directories should I put on ssd and which on the hdds.And if is possible a way to use simultaneously for storage.Or at least when 1 is full the other.
Can you guide me?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by "And if is possible a way to use simultaneously for storage?"

Comment: While LVM lets you span a volume across two drives, it not really is recommended. When one drive fails you lose all data on both drives. Better to just manage your data And data or games can be on data partition(s) on other than /. I do not have games but lots of applications and use 9GB of my 30GB / (root) partition. All my files, Documents, Music, Pictures are on a separate data partition, originally on HDD, but now on new larger SSD. HDD is now mostly backup and test installs.

Comment: If you need help, in my opinion you should stick to a very simple layout & avoid all complexity as the added complexity could lead to potential for catastrophic problems down the road. Your end-use will control what's best for you, but you provided no specifics, not even release detail (nor what installer you plan on using, as there are currently four installers selected by the ISO & release you use for Ubuntu and *flavors*).  You are mostly limited by your imagination & setup, however your asking for help implies you should avoid any complexity.

Comment: You control what programs you add, and many are available in different formats (compiled from source, snaps, *debs*, flatpak, appimage).  Some allow you to fully control where to go, others go in specific places (so your control is setup by your mounts at install time or later changes you make). You've provided no details as to what you are intending.. so it's unanswerable as you've asked...

Answer (score 1):

You make it too complicated thinking these applications you install will be massive. That is not how a Linux system is, the libraries for the applications are most likely installed in the base system. This is where most all of your applications will come from, the system installation methods. Not some random huge files you will download from a web site. A 120GB SSD should be more than enough for this, if wanting to do it one of your hard disk drives can be your `/home/user_name` directory this makes sense. As large media files and those types of things can be stored on it. The SSD reserved for the system files that need that fast access for loading programs. Then in the future when needing more space you can add another drive to be mounted under your `/home/user_name` directory for easy access to the file you put on it.

The install method taking this into consideration. Is to do the install using the SSD for the `/` partitiion. With one of the HDD as the location of the /`home` partition. By using the second drive as the `/home` partition this is where the `user_name` account will be placed. This will give you large space for your media and the best option for the system files. Make certain to select the formatting of each partition to ensure nothing is left on the drives when you install to them.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the last answer, keep the SSD for the OS and other core applications.  Then just map the other drives for use as storage of other mixed files.